# String split by two different delimiters

Tags: ruby, string, split

I have strings like this '`some-dasd\dasd-dasdas\dasdas-dasd-das\dsad`'.
I need to split the string to array by two different symbols `'\'` and `'-'`, so I would like to get the array `['some', 'dasd', 'dasd', 'dasdas', 'dasdas', 'dasd', 'das' ,'dsad']`.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
"ome-dasd\dasd-dasdas\dasdas-dasd-das\dsad".split(/\\|-/)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: But this doesn't work for the case where delimiters are next to one another \- gives you some blank elements.

Answer (score 11):

You can split string using regexp:

```
 mystring.split(/[-\\]/)
```

Comment: @lucapette you're going to have to excuse my relative ignorance of regexp - both this answer and yours seem equivalent to me? Why would one be better than the other?

Comment: @Russel They are absolutely equivalent in terms of *matching* but this one is more concise and it is more maintainable. For example suppose you want to add the `%`. This one will become `[-\\%]`, mine would become `\\|-|%`. And probably it's a matter of taste too :)

Comment: Yes, I think you're right it's more readable/maintainable, especially when more characters are added. However the pedant in me thinks it's only fair to point out that your answer uses less characters in the two character example and the same number in the three character example!