# Split by multiple delimiters in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, string, split

I need to make an array from a string, and I have to use multiple delimiters (apart from the space):

! @ $ # % ^ & * ( ) - = _ + [ ] : ; , . / < > ? \ |

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509307/split-string-by-multiple-delimiters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375729/string-split-by-two-different-delimiters), and the solution seems to be to use:

```
my_string.split(/[\s!@$#%^&*()-=_+[]:;,./<>?\|]/)
```

#### This is the exercise:

Given a sentence, return an array containing every other word.
Punctuation is not part of the word unless it is a contraction.
In order to not have to write an actual language parser, there won't be any punctuation too complex.
There will be no " ' " that is not part of a contraction.

Assume each of these  charactsrs are not to be considered:

! @ $ # % ^ & * ( ) - = _ + [ ] : ; , . / < > ? \ |

Examples:

```
alternate_words("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.")  # => ["Lorem", "dolor", "amet"]
alternate_words("Can't we all get along?")      # => ["Can't", "all", "along"]
alternate_words("Elementary, my dear Watson!")  # => ["Elementary", "dear"]
```

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
def every_other_word(sentence)
  my_words = []
  words = sentence.split(/[\s!@$^&*()-=_+[\]:;,.\/#%<>?\|]/)
  words.each_with_index do |w, i|
    next if i.odd?
    my_words << w
  end
  my_words
end
```

This is the error I get:

`$ ruby ./session2/3-challenge/7_array.rb
./session2/3-challenge/7_array.rb:14: premature end of char-class: /[\s!@$^&*()-=_+[\]:;,.\/#%<>?\|]/`

Comment: You need to escape `[`, `]`, `/` with a backslash (and eventually `\\` if you want this character too, otherwise you don't need to escape the pipe). Put the hyphen at the beginning or at the end of the class or escape it, since the hyphen in a character class is used to define a range of characters (see the ascii table).

Comment: Assuming that Ruby uses the `/../` paradigm delimiter and quote like operator, the first regex `my_string.split(/[\s!@$#%^&*()-=_+[]:;,./<>?\|]/)` has a problem, the `/` in the class is not escaped (it doubles as a delimiter). Beyond that, the class terminates `[\s!@$#%^&*()-=_+[]`<-here. The second regex `words = sentence.split(/[\s!@$^&*()-=_+[\]:;,.\/#%<>?\|]/)` is absolutely fine.

Comment: You need to escape the `-` as well or put it at the end otherwise you've got a range.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the mentioned delimiting characters have special meaning in regular expression literals. For example, `]` isn't the `]` character but [the end of a character class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes). The linked page should list all of them and explain their meaning.

Those characters need to be escaped in regular expression literals by preceding each with `\`. In this character class `-`, `[`, `]`, `/` and `\` need to be escaped (`^` only needs to if it's the first character and `-` only if it isn't the last character which it isn't):

```
/[\s!@$#%^&*()\-=_+\[\]:;,.\/<>?\\|]/
```

You can also let Ruby do the work with [`Regexp.escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) (aka `Regexp.quote`). It escapes every special character but the resulting regular expression will be equivalent:

```
escaped_characters = Regexp.escape('!@$#%^&*()-=_+[]:;,./<>?\|')
/[\s#{escaped_characters}]/
```

By the way, `\s` isn't just space like within double-quoted string literals (a weird feature), it matches other ASCII whitespace characters too (`\n`, `\t`, `\r`, `\f` and `\v`).

Answer (score 0):

You have been told there are no apostrophes and you are to disregard:

BADDIES = '!@$#%^&*()-=_+[]:;,./<>?\|'

so why not:

- remove the `BADDIES` with [String#ydelete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-delete);
- split the string into words with [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split);
- group the words in pairs with [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice); and
- select the first word of each pair [Enumerable#first](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-first) and [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

We can write:

```
str = "Now it the time for all good Rubiests to come to the aid of their " +
      "fellow coders (except for Bob)! Is that not true?"

str.delete(BADDIES).split.each_slice(2).map(&:first)
  #=> ["Now", "the", "for", "good", "to", "to", "aid", "their",
  #    "coders", "for", "Is", "not"]
```

Look, Ma! No regex!

Comment: The OP's question sounds like homework, otherwise why would he use regex for this simple 'exercise'.